# How can I make the script (below) to repeat for a certain number of time which I will define every time I need?

Tags: excel, vba

Hi Have the below script which is working okay, for creating Service Orders in SAP.

the Issue is that if I need like 3 or more service order, I need to run it 3 times and so on...

I would like to modify this scripts so that if I need like 3 Service Orders, I just put the number of times I want it to run and leave it working until done.

any help?

```
Sub MACRO_SO_CREATION()

Dim Application, SapGuiAuto, Connection, WScript, session, coll1

If Not IsObject(Application) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set Application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
   Set Connection = Application.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
   Set session = Connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject session, "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject Application, "on"
End If
'session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/niw31"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtAUFPAR-PM_AUFART").Text = "ZS01"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtCAUFVD-IWERK").Text = "FKIA"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtCAUFVD-IWERK").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtCAUFVD-IWERK").caretPosition = 4
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1100/tabsTS_1100/tabpIHKZ/ssubSUB_AUFTRAG:SAPLCOIH:1120/subTERM:SAPLCOIH:7300/subSUB_ADD:SAPLCOIH:7320/chkCAUFVD-AUTERM").Selected = False
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1100/subSUB_KOPF:SAPLCOIH:1102/subSUB_TEXT:SAPLCOIH:1103/cntlLTEXT/shell").Text = "TOTAL BLK 17-XXX-XXX: " + vbCr + "" + vbCr + "This SO has been created to cover the costs related to" + vbCr + "" + vbCr + "REQUESTED BY: " + vbCr + "RFQ N.: " + vbCr + "NOTIFICATIONs:" + vbCr + "QUOTE N.:" + vbCr + "PROCUREMENTE:" + vbCr + "NEEDED DATE:" + vbCr + "PO DELIVERY DATE:" + vbCr + "" + vbCr + "***************************HISTORY************************************" + vbCr + "DAY-MONTH-YEAR- RFQ sent to Procurement" + vbCr + ""
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1100/subSUB_KOPF:SAPLCOIH:1102/subSUB_TEXT:SAPLCOIH:1103/cntlLTEXT/shell").setSelectionIndexes 260, 260
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1100/subSUB_KOPF:SAPLCOIH:1102/subSUB_TEXT:SAPLCOIH:1103/cntlLTEXT/shell").firstVisibleLine = "7"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1100/tabsTS_1100/tabpIHKZ/ssubSUB_AUFTRAG:SAPLCOIH:1120/subSUB_ADRESSE:SAPLIPAR:0704/tabsTSTRIP_700/tabpKUND/ssubTSTRIP_SCREEN:SAPLIPAR:0130/subADRESSE:SAPLIPAR:0150/ctxtVIQMEL-KUNUM").Text = "66100"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1100/tabsTS_1100/tabpIHKZ/ssubSUB_AUFTRAG:SAPLCOIH:1120/subHEADER:SAPLCOIH:0154/ctxtCAUFVD-INGPR").Text = "200"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1100/tabsTS_1100/tabpIHKZ/ssubSUB_AUFTRAG:SAPLCOIH:1120/subHEADER:SAPLCOIH:0154/ctxtCAUFVD-VAPLZ").Text = "3166-PUR"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1100/tabsTS_1100/tabpIHKZ/ssubSUB_AUFTRAG:SAPLCOIH:1120/subHEADER:SAPLCOIH:0154/ctxtCAUFVD-ILART").Text = "190"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1100/tabsTS_1100/tabpIHKZ/ssubSUB_AUFTRAG:SAPLCOIH:1120/subTERM:SAPLCOIH:7300/ctxtCAUFVD-GSTRP").Text = ""
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1100/tabsTS_1100/tabpIHKZ/ssubSUB_AUFTRAG:SAPLCOIH:1120/subTERM:SAPLCOIH:7300/ctxtCAUFVD-GLTRP").Text = "14.12.2022"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1100/tabsTS_1100/tabpIHKZ/ssubSUB_AUFTRAG:SAPLCOIH:1120/subAVO:SAPLCOI0:0310/ctxtAFVGD-ARBPL").Text = "3166-pur"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1100/tabsTS_1100/tabpIHKZ/ssubSUB_AUFTRAG:SAPLCOIH:1120/subAVO:SAPLCOI0:0310/ctxtAFVGD-ARBPL").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1100/tabsTS_1100/tabpIHKZ/ssubSUB_AUFTRAG:SAPLCOIH:1120/subAVO:SAPLCOI0:0310/ctxtAFVGD-ARBPL").caretPosition = 8
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1100/subSUB_KOPF:SAPLCOIH:1102/subSUB_TEXT:SAPLCOIH:1103/cntlLTEXT/shell").setSelectionIndexes 0, 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1100/subSUB_KOPF:SAPLCOIH:1102/subSUB_TEXT:SAPLCOIH:1103/cntlLTEXT/shell").firstVisibleLine = "1"
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[0]/menu[3]").Select
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1100/tabsTS_1100/tabpILOA").Select
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1100/tabsTS_1100/tabpILOA/ssubSUB_AUFTRAG:SAPLCOIH:1150/subILOA:SAPMILA0:7000/txtILOA-MSGRP").Text = "RFQ2-XXX"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1100/tabsTS_1100/tabpILOA/ssubSUB_AUFTRAG:SAPLCOIH:1150/subILOA:SAPMILA0:7000/txtILOA-EQFNR").Text = "TEPA 22| TO QUOTE DAY/MONTH"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1100/tabsTS_1100/tabpILOA/ssubSUB_AUFTRAG:SAPLCOIH:1150/subILOA:SAPMILA0:7000/txtILOA-EQFNR").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1100/tabsTS_1100/tabpILOA/ssubSUB_AUFTRAG:SAPLCOIH:1150/subILOA:SAPMILA0:7000/txtILOA-EQFNR").caretPosition = 27
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1100/tabsTS_1100/tabpIHKZ").Select
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1100/tabsTS_1100/tabpILOA").Select
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press

End Sub
```

Comment: Put it in a loop using an input box to capture the number of times? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am really not an expert on this... However was trying to have the script go back to an specific excel cell and get from the the number of time need to repeat... but still cant do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to construct a loop - or at least one way to do it.

```
Sub run_a_loop()
            
    number_of_times = InputBox("How many times should this run?", "Input request")
    
    If IsNumeric(number_of_times) Then
        For n = 1 To number_of_times
            ' replace this with your code
            Debug.Print "Do something " & n & "/" & number_of_times
        Next
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I am really not an expert on this... hard for me to work from the script above, any further explanation ?

Comment: You have a rountine: `Sub MACRO_SO_CREATION()` that performs an action. If you replace the `Debug.Print` line with `MACRO_SO_CREATION` and run the run_a_loop() routine, it will ask you how many times you want it to run. Select a number and it will call your macro that many times.